# Can someone please clarify what happens in _getitem_ function? Thanks

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, huggingface-transformers

I understand that output contains the all of encodings, token type ids, attention_mask, and corresponding labels as tensors. I would like to understand the inner working of **getitem** function and the need of getting label lengths with **len** function.

```
class NewsGroupsDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, encodings, labels):
        self.encodings = encodings
        self.labels = labels

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        item = {k: torch.tensor(v[idx]) for k, v in self.encodings.items()}
        item["labels"] = torch.tensor([self.labels[idx]])
        return item

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)

# convert our tokenized data into a torch Dataset
train_dataset = NewsGroupsDataset(train_encodings, train_labels)
valid_dataset = NewsGroupsDataset(valid_encodings, valid_labels)
```

Comment: it's one of the "magic" functions (nothing Pytorch specific). You can read about those functions [here](https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/)

Comment: what does this line do? `item = {k: torch.tensor(v[idx]) for k, v in self.encodings.items()}`

Answer (score 1):

Python defines many special methods for classes. These methods define the behavior of the class in certain situations. You're probably already familiar with the `__init__` special method, that gets invoked when a new instance of the class is created. [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) is another special method that is called when you use subscription on an instance of the class (i.e. square brackets `[]`), and [`__len__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) is called when you use pass an instance of your class to the built-in `len` function.

As for Pytorch, we must implement these methods because that's what Pytorch's `DataLoader` object expects. It uses these methods to sample your dataset and know when it is done sampling the dataset. Though `DataLoader` uses many abstractions to support different sampling and multi-process operations, it basically needs `__len__` in order to know the maximum index it can query from the dataset, and it uses `__getitem__` to sample the indices it needs.

For example, when you're using random sampling with 0 workers, the following snippets do effectively the same thing

```py
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

train_dataset = NewsGroupsDataset(train_encodings, train_labels)
data_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=5, shuffle=True)
for items in data_loader:
    # items now contains batches of samples of size 5 from your dataset
```

and

```py
# For demonstration purposes only, do NOT sample your datasets like this (use DataLoader)!
import random
from torch.utils.data import default_collate

def random_batches(dataset, batch_size, shuffle):
    indices = list(range(len(dataset)))  # uses Dataset.__len__
    if shuffle:
        random.shuffle(indices)
    batch = []
    for i in indices:
        batch.append(dataset[i])  # uses Dataset.__getitem__
        if len(batch) == batch_size:
            yield default_collate(batch)
            batch = []
    if batch:
        yield default_collate(batch)

train_dataset = NewsGroupsDataset(train_encodings, train_labels)
for items in random_batches(train_dataset, batch_size=5, shuffle=True):
    # items now contains batches of samples of size 5 from your dataset
```

Note that `default_collate` is a function that takes a list of samples and converts them into stacks of batch-sized tensors. The implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py#L84) if you're curious of the details.

`DataLoader` also supports a lot of other cool things, like *multiple workers* (probably most important), custom sampling schemes, custom data collation, pinned memory, dropping last non-full batch, and more. Pytorch does most of the work for you with this class, you just need to write the dataset object with `__len__` and `__getitem__` implementations.

Comment: i think the question is a little bit misleading because it seems that s/he doesnt want to know how the "magic" function works but rather what happens in this exact function body

Answer (score 0):

`__getitem__` is a method used to get an item from the invoked instances’ attribute. `__getitem__` is mostly used with containers like `list`, `tuple`, etc.

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.item[index]


e = Example([1, 2, 3])
print(f"First item: {e[0]}")
# First item: 1

print(f"Second item: {e[1]}")
# Second item: 2

print(f"Third item: {e[2]}")
# Third item: 3
```

Comment: what does this line do? `item = {k: torch.tensor(v[idx]) for k, v in self.encodings.items()}`

Comment: @Shanuka That's a dictionary comprehension. Equivalent to `item={}` followed by `for k in self.encodings: item[k] = torch.tensor(self.encodings[k][idx])`. It is creating a dictionary with the same keys as `self.encodings` but the values in the new dictionary are a single element of the associated value.